# Цикл по объекту, ключи одинаковые - значения перезаписываются

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, map

Есть 2 объекта

```
/* Приходящий список */
    var rezbi = {
          "e938af08-1fc9-11e9-ab25-005056890020": {
            "Наименование": "Резьба P(SS)-ДУ25-L32",
            "Свойства": {
              "Наименование резьбы": "G 1\"",
              "Длинна резьбы": "32",
            },
          },
          "1f997369-1fca-11e9-ab25-005056890020": {
            "Наименование": "Резьба P(SS)-ДУ25-L157",
            "Свойства": {
              "Наименование резьбы": "G 1\"",
              "Длинна резьбы": "157",
            },
          },
          "90e6eb98-2066-11e9-ab25-005056890020": {
            "Наименование": "Резьба Р(SS)-ДУ25-L192",
            "Свойства": {
              "Наименование резьбы": "G 1\"",
              "Длинна резьбы": "192",
             },
            },
        }

/* Актуальные резьбы */
 var spisok_akt_rezb= {
      "Короткий левый": {
        "Наименование резьбы": "G 1\"",
        "Длинна резьбы": 30,
      },
      "Короткий правый": {
        "Наименование резьбы": "G 1\"",
        "Длинна резьбы": 30,
      },
      "Длинный": {
        "Наименование резьбы": "G 1\"",
        "Длинна резьбы": 65,
      }
    }
```

**Хочется получить массив всех Длинн резьб с приходящего списка, например:**

```
{
  "G 1\"": [ 32, 157, 192 ],
}
```

**Чтобы потом найти ближайшее к актуальной резьбе значение.**

Но пока получается что, ключи одинаковые - значения перезаписываются

```
var new_obj = {};
for (let key in select){
    for (let key2 in rezbi){
        /* Сравниваем резьбы */
        if (rezbi[key2]['Свойства']['Наименование резьбы'] === 
            select[key]['Наименование резьбы']){
                /* заполняем новый объект */
                new_obj[select[key]['Наименование резьбы']] = rezbi[key2]['Свойства']['Длинна резьбы'];
        }
    }
}
```

На выходе получается так, перезаписывает последним значением

```
{
  "G 1\"": "192",
}
```

Либо так, если использовать присваивание со сложением и добавить пробел между значениями

```
{
  "G 1\"": "undefined32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 157 157 157 157 157 157 157 157 157 192 192 192 192 192 192 192 192 192 ",
}
```

- Оборачивать ключи в массив пробовал, выдает весь список.
- Менять местами ключи и значения тоже пробовал.

Устал с разных сторон копать, может быть есть элегантное решение?

Comment: более элегантное решение - использовать вместо массива,  `new Set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно Вас понял ,то можно так -

```js
let data = {
          "e938af08-1fc9-11e9-ab25-005056890020": {
            "Наименование": "Резьба P(SS)-ДУ25-L32",
            "Свойства": {
              "Наименование резьбы": "G 1\"",
              "Длинна резьбы": "32",
            },
          },
          "1f997369-1fca-11e9-ab25-005056890020": {
            "Наименование": "Резьба P(SS)-ДУ25-L157",
            "Свойства": {
              "Наименование резьбы": "G 1\"",
              "Длинна резьбы": "157",
            },
          },
          "90e6eb98-2066-11e9-ab25-005056890020": {
            "Наименование": "Резьба Р(SS)-ДУ25-L192",
            "Свойства": {
              "Наименование резьбы": "G 1\"",
              "Длинна резьбы": "192",
             },
            },
        }

const getCollectInformationAboutLength = data => Object.keys(data).reduce( (result, key) =>{
  let name = data[key]['Свойства']['Наименование резьбы'];
  let length = data[key]['Свойства']['Длинна резьбы'];
  
  
  let lengths = result[name] || (result[name] = []);
  
  if(!lengths.includes(length)){
    lengths.push(length);
  }
  
  
  
  return result;
}, {} );

console.log(getCollectInformationAboutLength(data));
```

Возможно что я неправильно Вас понял и если нужно выбрать элементы основываясь на диапозоне длины, то это можно сделать так -

```js
let data = {
          "e938af08-1fc9-11e9-ab25-005056890020": {
            "Наименование": "Резьба P(SS)-ДУ25-L32",
            "Свойства": {
              "Наименование резьбы": "G 1\"",
              "Длинна резьбы": "32",
            },
          },
          "1f997369-1fca-11e9-ab25-005056890020": {
            "Наименование": "Резьба P(SS)-ДУ25-L157",
            "Свойства": {
              "Наименование резьбы": "G 1\"",
              "Длинна резьбы": "157",
            },
          },
          "90e6eb98-2066-11e9-ab25-005056890020": {
            "Наименование": "Резьба Р(SS)-ДУ25-L192",
            "Свойства": {
              "Наименование резьбы": "G 1\"",
              "Длинна резьбы": "192",
             },
            },
        }




const getItemByLengthRange = (data, from, to = NaN) => {
  if(Number.isNaN(to)){
    to = from;
  }
  
  
  return Object.keys(data).reduce( (result, key) => {
    let name = data[key]['Свойства']['Наименование резьбы'];
    let length = data[key]['Свойства']['Длинна резьбы'];
    
    if(length >= from && length <= to){
      result[key] = data[key];
    }
      
    return result;
  }, {} );
}

console.log(getItemByLengthRange(data, 32, 160));
```

Comment: Я ещёраз прочел то, чтовы написали и мне кажется что я Вас не до конца понял. Вы можете сказать, что вы хотите сделать? То есть я точно понял, что  данн массив со значениями. А что потом? Неговорите о том, как вы хотите сделать. Скажите что вы хотите получить витоге.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.

Только непонятно что делает 

 `let lengths = result[name] || (result[name] = []);`

Comment: @Николай присваивает массив переменной lengths. Сам массив ссылка на массив извлекается из объекта result по ключу name. Только в первом случаи мы берем уже существующий массив result[name], а во втором сначала его туда кладем result[name] = []. У Вас наверное путаница возникла из-за того что вы забыли,  что в результате операции присвояния возвращается присваиваемого значение. То есть можно с натяжкой сказать, что выражения result[name] и result[name] = [], равнозначны.